# Don't have a momentary switch, what else can I use?

Tags: switches, raspberry-pi

Hi everyone and apologies if this is a really dumb question.

I'm following this to control the GPIO on a raspberry PI: 
[image: Circuit Diagram]

I bought a starter kit which has 2 mini push buttons, but I've no idea if they can be used?

[image: breadboard]

If not there's nowhere round here I can buy a switch so it'll be a day or two, is there any way to DIY a suitable switch?

Any help would be great and sorry about the question. You're probably sick of raspberry pi questions but I have no one to ask.

Comment: That looks like a suitable momentary switch, assuming that it's normally-open.

Comment: Don't forget the key-bounce!

Comment: @pjc50 this is where I sound really stupid - the switch they use has 2 connectors, where the one I have has 4. I don't know what to do with it...

Comment: "You're probably sick of raspberry pi questions but I have no one to ask."  -- I bet http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ isn't sick of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work.  They have 4 pins for structural strength, since they are meant to be soldered on a pcb.  It has two pairs of pins, where each pin in a pair is electrically connected to the other, as illustrated in the following diagram (taken from google images):

[image]

As you can see, pins `1` & `2` are connected, and so are `3` & `4`.

If it is normally closed instead of normally open, you can still make it work as expected by tweaking the software (may be as simple as inverting the logic).

Comment: ahh, thankyou I'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

You can get a button like that from Radio Shack for a buck or two.  There's nothing magic about it.  The mini buttons look momentary.  Wire one up to an LED and see.